# Why does `telnet` buffer FTP control connection lines?

Tags: ftp, telnet

RFC 1123 says

```
Implementors MUST NOT assume any correspondence between READ
boundaries on the control connection and the Telnet EOL
sequences (CR LF).

DISCUSSION:
    Thus, a server-FTP (or User-FTP) must continue reading
    characters from the control connection until a complete
    Telnet EOL sequence is encountered, before processing
    the command (or response, respectively).  Conversely, a
    single READ from the control connection may include
    more than one FTP command.
```

I'm wondering if this requirement is still relevant today.

I toyed a little with Linux Netkit's `telnet` command (the one shipped with Ubuntu). When I open communication to a telnet server, the client is very paranoid about flushing data. `telnet` immediately turns key presses into packets and fetches them.

Given that FTP stands on top of Telnet, if I `telnet` to an FTP server, I'd expect the same paranoid behaviour. Instead, `telnet` buffers my key presses until the newline. It fetches only whole FTP command packets. Only when talking to FTP servers.

Why does `telnet` bother to buffer characters for FTP specifically given the requirement above exists? It even buffers past the MTU limit (and segments in the TCP layer).

`man telnet` is silent on this topic and I can't find Netkit's source code. ([One of the links is broken and the other one leads to an empty repository](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~dholland/computers/old-netkit.html).) In any case, `man telnet` says "The source code is not comprehensible", so I'm pessimistic about finding a comment somewhere that would explain the rationale.

Is there some sort of update specification or practical constraint that nulls an implementation's freedom to fetch half-finished FTP commands? What am I missing?

Why does `telnet` buffer FTP control connection lines?

Comment: Wrong! FTP and Telnet are different protocols, different RFCs.  Use `wireshark` to watch `ftp` and `telnet` conversations.

Comment: @waltinator True, but FTP and Telnet "overlap". See https://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2009/ftp-using-raw-commands-and-telnet/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Telnet has two basic modes of operation: line mode and character mode. The default mode is always line mode. The telnet application then has to negotiate with the remote server about what it can and cannot support. This is done through a system called TELOPT and the special character 255 known as IAC - Interpret As Command.

Only when the two ends have agreed that they can do character at once, and even that the remote end will echo back received characters, will the link be in the traditional interactive (non line buffered) mode.

Since FTP is not meant to be manually interacted with using telnet it doesn't support any of the advanced telnet TELOPT features. Therefore character mode can never be negotiated.

All this is in [rfc854](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854)

Comment: Hmm. Something doesn't feel right. Page 5 of RFC 854 says, indeed, that the default is linemode. By "negotiate character mode" I'm assuming you mean "IAC DONT/WONT LINEMODE" (RFC 1184), but it's really weird that I'm sniffing the telnet-only (non-FTP) traffic and this negotiation never appears, even though the client is flushing early... and the server is echoing. I can see the "IAC DO ECHO", though. Can this be enough to trigger character mode?

Comment: Oh - I guess it's because of the Suppress Go Ahead. "the sender of data which is suppressing GO AHEADs should attempt to actually transmit characters as soon as possible" (RFC 858). Never mind; thanks.